# Summary of Sparse Matrix returns Triangular Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, methods, sparse-matrix

Curious as to the following behavior:

```
require(Matrix)
M <- Matrix(data = 1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, sparse = TRUE) # Actually dense, but bear with me.
summary(M)
```

This returns a sparse matrix in COO format, represented as a 3-column `data.frame`, *but for upper-triangular portion only!* I.e. there are only 6 observations in the resulting table, whereas the 3x3 matrix clearly has 9 non-zero entries; we have seemingly lost information, and this surprises me as a user of the class and method.

What's going on here? Bonus points if you mention how to access the relevant documentation. E.g., I try

```
methods(summary)             # Notes there is a summary.sparseMatrix-method, but...
?summary.sparseMatrix        # Doesn't return anything
?summary.sparsematrix-method # Doesn't return anything

showMethods("summary")       # Notes there are methods for objects = c("dsCMatrix", "sparseMatrix"), so we try:
?summary.dsCMatrix           # Doesn't return anything...
?summary.sparseMatrix        # Doesn't return anything.
```

It would be easy enough if I could access the sub-routine itself or any documentation. Calling `debug(summary); summary(M)` and then using `s` to step into the method call doesn't "work", as the following is instantly output to console, `exiting from summary(M)`, whereafter the (upper-triangular) summary result is printed.

Thanks for your time and insight!

Comment: `?dsCMatrix-class` does have details - though I admit that the `?Matrix` help page description would not lead me to expect that output.

Comment: Thanks @StephenHenderson, looks like I've created a sparse symmetric matrix when I only wanted a sparse matrix. Now if only I could figure out where I (implicitly) specified this. Edit: I suppose it was inferred from the provided values.

Comment: Indeed. PS when you get something unexpected generally the simplest thing to find out what going on is type `class(whatever)` then `?the-class`